# Can I put a link inside a title attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm using the [jQuery Fancybox plugin](http://fancy.klade.lv/) to create a modal window with the link's `href` as the content, and the `title` as its caption. I'd like to be able to have a clickable link in the caption (in this case to lead to a larger map) but I can't put an `<a>` tag into the `title` attribute. How might I go about putting this link in through Javascript, jQuery, or other methods?

```
<a class='iframe' href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%235+Health+Department+Drive,+Troy,+MO+63379&amp;ll=38.979228,-90.97847&amp;z=13&amp;iwloc=near&amp;num=1&amp;output=embed' title='Google Map to Lincoln County Health Department'>Map to LCHD</a>
```

[image: What it looks like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this plugin, but this method comes to mind.

You can bury content elements within the anchor and modify you plugin to use the elements that your introduce.  For example:

```
<a class='iframe' 
   href='http://maps.google.com/blahlblahlbah' 
   title='Google Map to Lincoln County Health Department'>Map to LCHD
   <span class="title-href" style="display: none">http://zebrakick.com</span>
</a>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the element => destination_link map as an object, and fetch values from it for redirection.

```
var linkmap = {
   lincoln:   '/location/3/',
   someplace: '/location/99'
}
```

Now you can use the values from linkmap in your click event (with [] or  . operator)

Answer (score 0):

I passed additional data along with the :

```
<a href="images/product.jpg" title="Product nummer 1" data-title-url="http://google.nl" rel="fancybox">
```

and used a custom callback for setting the title:

```
{
    //fancybox options array
    titleFormat: function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts){
        var currentElement = currentArray[currentIndex];

        var html = "<h1>" + title + "</h1>";
        var titleUrl = $(currentElement).data("title-url");
        if (titleUrl) {
            var link = $("<a>", {href: titleUrl, text: titleUrl, target: "_blank"});
            html += " (" + link.prop("outerHTML") + ")";
        }

        return html;
    },
}
```

http://fancybox.net/api

http://api.jquery.com/data/